# How can I see webrequests Facebook sends me

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook

I am wondering how I can see exactly what webrequests I am receiving from Facebook?

Lets say that we are on Facebook event and I want to invite all my 1000 friends.
I start clicking all my friends one by one and at some point Facebook sets a limit of 498 and then I continue to do all the clicks until I reach 498 and then it says you cant invite anyone else.

Facebook to do this at some point sends back an `ajax.php` page as a packet and sets this limit. This ajax php page i'm trying to find somehow.
I've tried some ajax jQuery capture Chrome extensions but I dont quite understand them much.

Do you have any idea of how I can track any ajax php request from Facebook to my browser to set this limit?

I am using Chrome Extension Live HTTP Headers
and this shows me anything that Facebook webrequest is "POST" in my browser.

But i dont think its actually all of them.
Because its only loading the photos of the chat
and some thread updates.

Here is a video of what limitation is showing in my frame of friends invite in facebook.

[Youtube Video Here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yq8cs_kq3Ds)

Answer (score 1):

Press F12 and find the network requests section of your browser's dev tools.

http://www.devtoolsecrets.com/secret/general-finding-the-development-tools.html

Comment: i've tried but it doesnt show ALL the requests of facebook. For example the "typing" and "seen" of chat, it doesnt show them at all.

Comment: @GiwrgosPetropopoulos could be websocket traffic that will show up in a different way than you might expect http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the process. Web servers don't send requests to web browsers. They only respond to requests sent from the web browser.

When you click to invite friends you are sending an ajax request **to** Facebooks server. That ajax request passes the information about the event, you and your friend to a method on the server. Part of that method is to check and see if the limit on invitations has been exceeded. If not it sends your invitation and sends a response to your ajax request showing this person was invited. However if the limit has been reached the invitation is not sent and the response comes back from your ajax request stating that the limit has been exceeded.

If you know what your doing, you use Chrome or Firefox developers tools to debug javascript and follow the ajax request to the server and the response from the server. But this is difficult with the minified javascript. There are tools to deminify the javascript making it easier.

However, if you're looking for a way around the invitation limit. It's not going to happen. This all occurs on the Facebook servers to which you do not have access.

Comment: thanks for your answer first of all i dont know if im wrong. But if you go to invite someone in one event, you can click your friends and a (tick) is going to be on the right side of the event frame. So when you click your friends and you reach 300 friends click on 301 click it will appear one limit on the top of the frame. it will say 300/500. So facebook (as i can guess) sends me a webrequest to change the css of the frame like "There is a limit now. Show to the frame 300/500" and as you click it goes 300++. Is this more clear now?

Comment: I added at the main post one video link.

Comment: @GiwrgosPetropopoulos that behavior could easily be client-side validation done in javascript if you're not seeing any network traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). With Fiddler you can see all requests (also HTTPS requests with an intermediate certificate), modify those or simply replay requests. It's worth a try and a must have for each web developer